# Semantic-UI avoid form validation trigger for some button click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, semantic-ui

So by default Semantic-ui doesn't have any way to prevent clicks which trigger the validation, once the form has been setup, as the validation is handled onsubmit directly. This is important if you have multiple buttons on the page and only want some to trigger the validation and the rest perhaps to be able to postback, or do other things minus triggering the form validation.

I checked some answers that talk about changing the input from a type=submit to a type=button, but you lose the design ability especially the ability to add an icon and is not the ideal solution.

Am posting this question, since my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34858669/820754), got deleted by the moderator, even though I have a working fiddle and a detailed answer on how to achieve this.

Reposting the entire answer here, incase anyone needs help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement this in a different way, as the button type=button control while ignoring the validations, did not submit, and if I did submit manually the default event handler of semanticui would intervene and show the validation errors.

My use case two buttons, one a **save draft** and the other a **finalize** (final save). The first one had to save the data as is, without triggering the validations, while the other would trigger validations and then save.

*I am also implementing all the validators using data attributes that I custom implemented for this project, hence the form validator is inside a JS file.*

In my form validation's failure method, I included a delegate function which I could set on my page and depending on which button clicked it, then be able to return true or false.

#### My form validator inside a JS file

```
$('.ui.form').form({
    inline: true,
    on: 'submit',
    fields: formFields,
    transition: 'fade',
    keyboardShortcuts: false,
    onFailure: function () {
        var returnValue = false; //Default to false, since validations failed

        //If the delegate is present, fire it to evaluate
        if (typeof window.delegValidate == 'function') {
            returnValue = window.delegValidate();
        }

        //Ignore the toast if the delegate evaluated to TRUE
        if (!returnValue) {
            $('body')
                .toast({
                    title: 'Unable to save',
                    message: 'Please enter all required field data before saving.',
                    classProgress: 'red',
                    showProgress: 'top',
                    progressUp: true,
                    position: 'bottom right',
                    showIcon: 'red exclamation triangle'
                });
        }
        return returnValue; // false is required if you don't want to let it submit
    }
});
```

and on my page I attached a function to the window, since my form validation is inside a JS file.

#### Page function

```
       //For all postback buttons, save the id value in a hidden field for use in the delegate
        $('.postbackButton').bind('click', function (e) {
            $('#ButtonClicked').val(this.id); // a hidden field on the page
        });

        //setting the delegate for use in the form validations
        window.delegValidate = function () {
            //For the save button, just ignore the validations and return true
            //This in turn is invoked by the failure method of the form validation that is 
            //dynamically attached to the page, and hence this return value is respected
            //over the false that is otherwise sent back for when we want to interrupt the page
            //since there are errors normally.
            if ($('#ButtonClicked').val() == 'Save')
                return true;
            else // if value is finalize, let it return false
                return false;
        }
```

For other pages where I don't want this functionality, I can simply not write the delegate method and the default validation fires as expected on the submit button.

Also posted here [Ignore SemanticUI validation on some buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66821712/820754)

Hope this helps anyone looking for a better way of handling this scenario.